# Recursive fractal 2d tree drawing in webgl

Tags: javascript, tree, webgl, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw a simple binary fractal tree in webgl, however the branches aren't going in the proper angles I want. I am drawing the tree by plotting the points of the vertices into an array, then plugging that array into a float32array and later calling drawArrays(LINE_STRIPE).

This is for a programming assignment due this monday. I do remember drawing a binary fractal tree recursively back in high school, but it was done using scratch. It's also been a very long time since I did any math that needed trig.

The below funciton is a recursive function that pushes the coordinates of the vertices into an array, which will later be passed into a float32array.

```js
function createPoints(x, y, length, depth, angle, points)
{
  if(depth > 0)
  {
    //draws line
    points.push((x + length) * Math.sin(angle));
    points.push((y + length) * Math.cos(angle));

    let currentx = (x + length) * Math.sin(angle);
    let currenty = (y + length) * Math.cos(angle);

    //draw left branch
    angle += Math.PI / 4;
    console.log(angle);
    createPoints((x + length/2) * Math.sin(angle), (y + length/2) * Math.cos(angle), length/2, depth - 1, angle, points);

    //goes back somehow
    points.push(currentx);
    points.push(currenty);

    //draw right branch
    angle -= Math.PI / 2;
    console.log(angle);
    createPoints((x + length/2) * Math.sin(angle), (y + length/2) * Math.cos(angle), length/2, depth - 1, angle, points);
    return points;
  }
  return;
}
```

The expected output is a tree of recursion depth 2, which would be just a simple Y shape. The branches should be rotated 45 degrees from the base trunk. However, as you can see in my output, that is not the case:

[image]

The right branch actually is not at 45 degrees, although it seems close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LINE_STRIPE` is not the proper [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) type to do what you want, because a line strip is one coherently line.
Use the primitive type `LINES`. So each branch creates a separated line segment:

The function has to calculate the end point of the current branch and to add the 2 vertices for the line segment to the point list:

```js
let x2 = x + length * Math.sin(angle);
let y2 = y + length * Math.cos(angle);

points.push(x, y, x2, y2);
```

And 2 new branches at the end of the current branch by e recursive call:

```js
createPoints(depth-1, x2, y2, length/2, angle+Math.PI/4, points);
createPoints(depth-1, x2, y2, length/2, angle-Math.PI/4, points);
```

Complete coding of the function:

```js
function createPoints(depth, x, y, length, angle, points) {

    if (depth <= 0)
        return;

    // end of current line segment
    let x2 = x + length * Math.sin(angle);
    let y2 = y + length * Math.cos(angle);

    // add segment
    points.push(x, y, x2, y2);

    // create 2 branches
    createPoints(depth-1, x2, y2, length/2, angle+Math.PI/4, points);
    createPoints(depth-1, x2, y2, length/2, angle-Math.PI/4, points);
}
```

e.g. 4 levels:

```js
let points = [];
createPoints(4, 0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, points);
```

[image]

---

If you anyway want to use the primitive type `LINE_STRIP`, then each branch has to add a single end point, but has to return to this point after each child branch:

```
function createPointsStrip(depth, x, y, length, angle, points) {

    if (depth <= 0)
        return;

    // end of current line segment
    let x2 = x + length * Math.sin(angle);
    let y2 = y + length * Math.cos(angle);

    // add point
    points.push(x2, y2);

    // create 2 branches
    createPointsStrip(depth-1, x2, y2, length/2, angle+Math.PI/4, points);
    points.push(x2, y2);
    createPointsStrip(depth-1, x2, y2, length/2, angle-Math.PI/4, points);
    points.push(x2, y2);
}
```

The first point has to be add to the list of points, before the recursive function is called:

```js
let points = [0.0, -1.0];
createPointsStrip(4, 0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, points);
```

The generated primitive is completely different, but looks the same (in this case).

Comment: Why is it that in your tree, past the first branch, the branches go in an about 22.5 degree angle? My assignment expects every branch to branch off at 45 degrees. Also, how i go about using LINE in the assignment? The TA suggested to me to use LINE_STRIP and just redraw over an existing line to return to an old vertex.

Comment: I had another error where only half of my tree was being draw, and it was also being draw sideways. The reason why that happened is because you said x2 = x + length * Math.cos(angle), when it should've been sin, and y shouldve been mutiplied by cos.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. I had my starting angle be 0 instead of pi/2.

Comment: @EdmundLiang Anyway, I've changed it. now you can pass 0.